# Backing up XenServer VMs to a Windows share

Tags: backup, xenserver

I currently run two XenServers with a few VMs.

I have been looking into [this script solution](http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Xenserver+zero+downtime+vm+backup+%28only+system+disk%29) or possibly [this one](http://pastebin.com/b2HNrvZB), but it relies on an NFS share.

My environment is mostly Windows and I'd prefer to backup the whole VMs to Windows backup machines.

Answer (score 0):

follow the The backup python script has a configuration file with the backup to location. If you mount the windows share (with mount.cifs), you can use the backup script.

You can mount the windows share with something like:

mount.cifs //IP or Windows Server Name/sharename /backupmountpoint/ -o user=username password=password domain=Domain